# Restarting or resetting input signal independently of simulation time and many times

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have designed a signal by using the Signal Builder block in Simulink. During the run of my simulation, the signal builder is to restart depending on the satisfaction of a condition. The condition can be satisfied many times, so, the signal should start from the beginning each time. If I want to put it in another way: You can take step input instead of the designed signal. Step input is to be reset conditionally. How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen such a functionality built-in `Simulink` (maybe the newer versions have it?) but here is a workaround:

You can simulate passed time with an integrator that has a `Constant block` set to 1 as input. The point is that the integrator block has a reset port which you can connect to your condition. So, when your condition becomes true, the integrator restarts a time variable from 0 (which is set in the initial conditions). Beforehand, you need to have your signal saved in something like a `Table Lookup` block, which outputs the signal as a function of time. Then you connect the integrator output to the `Table Lookup` block.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your Signal Builder block in an [enabled subsystem](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/enabledsubsystem.html)? You probably need to set the `states when enabling` to `reset` for it to work. Have a look at [Create an Enabled Subsystem](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/enabled-subsystems.html) in the documentation for more details.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried to an enabled subsystem before. I understand that the output port returns the system to the specified initial condition. According to my trials , the designed signal does not rewind.  Actually, I put a step input inside the enabled block, enabled it with a pulse generator to be able to enable more than once, and set the port to reset with 0 IC. It does not work unfortunately. I might be missing something.